# XTB api difference in received data

Tags: c#, .net, stock, algorithmic-trading

I am receiving data from XTB API.

But I can't understand difference between `GOOGL.US_4` and `GOOGL.US_9`
It's like all stocks are doubled with `US_4` and `US_9` what does it mean? I can't find it anywhere on the internet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved it seems that US_4 means cfd from what i saw.